# Check if current date date is within current month

Tags: java, gwt, java.util.date

I'm aware there are several similiar questions. But mine is different in two points

1. Usage of `java.util.*` classes only (our server currently operates only with those)
2. I need to determine whether given date is after the specified date OR represents same day (typically today)

This is what I got:

```
if ((new Date().getMonth() == object.getDate().getMonth() && new Date().getYear() == object.getDate().getYear()
                                    && new Date().getDay() == object.getDate().getDay())
                                    || (new Date().after(object.getDate()) && new Date().getMonth() == object.getDate().getMonth()
                                            && new Date().getYear() == object.getDate().getYear()))
```

This thing works, but let's be honest - doesn't look really elegant. Is there way to do this in prettier way?

Comment: Don't instantiate so many `new Date()` objects. Just do it once, and use that variable.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't solve my problem, right?

Comment: Right, it was just a matter of code practice, that's why I didn't post an official answer. Just an idea: maybe you could have some functions. For example, `isToday`, that would contain all the logic until the first `||`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your solution, it's anyway worth optimizing it. For example, create `new Date()` only once. Also to make it more readable and shorter, extract `object.getDate()` as a variable above all these comparisons. One more way to solve your problem can be:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar min = getMinDateOfMonth();
        Calendar max = getMinDateOfMonth();
        max.set(Calendar.MONTH, min.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        if (min.getTime().before(object.getDate()) && max.getTime().after(object.getDate())) {
            // you're inside the month
        }
    }

    private static Calendar getMinDateOfMonth() {
        Calendar min = Calendar.getInstance();
        min.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        min.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        min.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        min.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        min.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return min;
    }
```